# Slider with sticky texts and buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider

I have a question about a slider that I need to make with Bootstrap 3.3.1. I would like to make an image slider with texts and 3 buttons hovering and centered over those images. So far so good, the tricky part is that I would like the text and buttons to remain still as the images slides (if that makes sence?) because the text is basically the same for the most part.

There is just a little part of the text that actually needs to be changed with the image/slide.
Exemple: ***The moon is red (red image behind), The moon is blue (blue image behind)*** (Only the word "red" and "blue" changes in that sentence but the rest doesn't fade or swipe with the image.)

How can I make this possible? and responsive.

Thank you,
I'm running out of ideas.

[Link to the folder](https://mega.nz/file/bj5E1CpB#udYW3ALoMBsifdw86PzB5YpBgM0-lLbMPwaWqPtpvTw)

there are so many JQuery files and JS that I thought it would be easier to share the folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide the code that you have written so far so that we could better understand the problem and be able to assist you.

Comment: added a link to the folder.

Comment: Hi! Instead of sharing a folder with all your code, adding a [minimal reproducible example would](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would  be more helpful for people trying to answer your question.